# I want a htaccess file to redirect to my subfolder build where my react app is located in linux server

Tags: reactjs, linux, apache, .htaccess, redhat

So my Ht access file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On



     
    
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule . /build/index.html [L]
    
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
    
    RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif|pdf|wav|wmv|wma|avi|mov|mp4|m4v|mp3|zip|js|ejs|csv|svg|css|json|env?)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

[But its showing 403 error on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r93KY.png)
I want to redirect every request to the build folder where my react app is located
How can i solve this problem

So i did some reserach and thats how my ht access file looks like now

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^$ /build/ [L]

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /build/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

its redirecting me to correct index.html
as you can see in this pic i am getting my correct meta description
[as you can see in this pic i am getting my correct meta description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQAN.png)

but in the console log its this throwing error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.876ac007.chunk.js:1:1)
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: http status 403 says "forbidden". That has nothing to do with rewriting. Something in your setup prevents the server from accessing the requested resources. Either file system permissions or your own application logic.

Comment: Actually the previous htaccess was deleted accidentally and it was running fine with it,problem arived when i tried to make a new one for the same thing

Comment: That points into a file permission issue. Or maybe naming of the file. Triple check file ownership and permissions and the exact naming.

Comment: If you have access to that http server's error log file, that might contain valuable information.

Comment: @arkascha Hey made some edits in the post can you checkout pls

Comment: Requests to js files get rewritten to that html file too, apparently. Which is why the JS interpreted tries to interpret html markup as js, throwing the syntax error.